# I want to extract string after = by rexgs in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a file that contains

```
{{cite web |url=http://www.canada.lu |title=Gouvernement du Canada -
 Government of Canada |publisher= |accessdate=20 February 2015}}


{{cite book
|url=https://books.google.com/?id=U3L6H8eOIb0C&amp;pg=PA117&amp;dq=Estonia+and+Luxembourg#PPA118,M1
|title=The Radical Right in Interwar Estonia |publisher=
|accessdate=20 February 2015 |isbn=9780312225988 |last1=Kasekamp
|first1=Andres
```

I wrote a code in `Java` by using `regular expression` to extract between `{{cite web ....}}`

```
Pattern Pattern3 = Pattern.compile("\\{cite book([^}]+)\\}", Pattern.DOTALL);

Matcher matcher3 = Pattern3.matcher(t);

Pattern Pattern4 = Pattern.compile("\\{cite web([^}]+)\\}", Pattern.DOTALL);

Matcher matcher4 = Pattern4.matcher (t);
```

It gives me all things between `{{cite web .... }}` and `{{cite book ...}}`

but I want to extract every strings after `=` and before `|`

like `title=The Radical Right in Interwar Estonia`

I want the **output** like this:

---

```
WEB:

Title = Gouvernement du Canada - Government of Canada
URL = http://www.canada.lu
Access Date =20 February 2015

BOOK:
Title =  The Radical Right in Interwar Estonia
URL = https://books.google.com/?id=U3L6H8eOIb0C&amp;pg=PA117&amp;dq=Estonia+and+Luxembourg#PPA118,M1
publisher = NULL
```

---

Thank you

**My [file](https://filebin.net/wu307hyp2bh2wpqf/Wiki.xml?t=fkqlozvo) that I want to extract from.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use 2 capturing groups and get continuous matches using the `\G` anchor. Using the negated character class `[^}]+` assumes that there can not be a `}` char in the keys or the values.

```
(?:\{\{[^|]*|\G(?!^))(?=[^}]*}})\|([^=]+)=([^|}]+)
```

In Java

```
String regex = "(?:\\{\\{[^|]*|\\G(?!^))(?=[^\\}]*\\}})\\|([^=]+)=([^|\\}]+)";
```

In parts

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `{{[^|]*` Match `{{` followed by matching any char except a `|`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close group
- `(?=[^}]*}})` Assert `}}` at the right
- `\|\h*` Match `|` and 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `([^=]+)` Capture **group 1**, match any char except `=`
- `=` Match the `=`
- `([^|}]+)` Capture **group 2**

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gnapCT/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/krA2yw)

Comment: thank you , but it not work , there is error .. also i need to extract between {{ cite book }}, or {{cite web }} separately.

Comment: @MSCS2019 What is the error? Did you see the demo? This will only get the values for cite book https://regex101.com/r/WvZPfc/1

Comment: that what apper to me :
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 0
?:\{\{cite book\b[^|]*|\G(?!^))(?=[^}]*}})\|([^=]+)=([^|}]+)
^
 at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:2015)
 

 at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2190)
 at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:2056)
 at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1778)
 at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1427)

Comment: Can you be more specific? What did not work? What was the error? Can you share the code that you tried that did not work?

Comment: @MSCS2019 Did you double escape the backslashes? `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:\\{\\{[^|]*|\\G(?!^))(?=[^\\}]*\\}})\\|([^=]+)=([^|\\}]+)");`

Comment: sorry , I was not attentive to Demo , there no error but it work but There are undesirable extractions . i want to share the file( that i want to extract from ) with you , how i can ?

Comment: You can open this link https://regex101.com/r/gnapCT/1 Then add a part of the text to it, and on the left top you can either update the regex or fork it and past the link here in the comments

Comment: thank you ,  i uploded here https://filebin.net/wu307hyp2bh2wpqf/Wiki.xml?t=fkqlozvo

Comment: also i uploded in the https://regex101.com/r/gnapCT/4 , you can see the result ..

Comment: it is work , you are THE BEST . but more than qustion ... what if i want extract spsific felides Like ( title , URL , puplisher ) with out any other else in {{cite book and i want extract ( title , URL ,access-date) in  cite web and so on

Comment: You could check the value of capture group 1 in the code. Group 1 contains the value of the key.

Comment: @MSCS2019 You could do it like this for example: https://ideone.com/Ar5yEe

Comment: sorry , when i try the last example, it is work but it give me the first result and ignor the rest .

Comment: @MSCS2019 I see that the value of group 1 can have trailing spaces. You could use trim for example https://ideone.com/ULFULx

Comment: YESSS , THANK YOU , SORRY if i will come back

Comment: i put a qustion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61465745/extract-by-regx-in-java if you can help .

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we need to detect `cite` entries and then parse their contents into fields as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61466470/13279831)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ParseWikiData {

    static final int PREFIX_GROUP = 1;
    static final int FIELD_NAME_GROUP = 3;
    static final int FIELD_VALUE_GROUP = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String entryRegex = "(?i:\\{\\{\\s*cite\\s+(book|journal)[^}]*\\}\\})";
        Pattern entryPattern = Pattern.compile(entryRegex);

        String fieldRegex = "(?i:(?<=^|\\|)(\\{\\{Cite\\s+(book|journal)\\s*)|([^{|}\\=]+)\\s*\\=\\s*([^|}]*))";
        Pattern fieldPattern = Pattern.compile(fieldRegex);

        String txt = readFile("wikisample.xml");

        Matcher entryMatcher = entryPattern.matcher(txt);
        int count = 0;
        while (entryMatcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Entry #" + ++count + ": prefix: " + entryMatcher.group(PREFIX_GROUP).trim());
            String content = entryMatcher.group(0).trim();
            Matcher fieldMatcher = fieldPattern.matcher(content);

            while (fieldMatcher.find()) {
                if (fieldMatcher.group(FIELD_NAME_GROUP) != null) {
                    String key = fieldMatcher.group(FIELD_NAME_GROUP).trim();
                    String value = fieldMatcher.group(FIELD_VALUE_GROUP).trim();
                    System.out.println("\t" + key + " = " + value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        return Files.lines(Path.of(fileName)).collect(Collectors.joining());
    }
}
```

For the sample wiki file, the following output is produced (detecting both books and journals):

```
Entry #1: prefix: book
    url = https://books.google.com/?id=U3L6H8eOIb0C&amp;pg=PA117&amp;dq=Estonia+and+Luxembourg#PPA118,M1
    title = The Radical Right in Interwar Estonia
    publisher = 
    accessdate = 20 February 2015
    isbn = 9780312225988
    last1 = Kasekamp
    first1 = Andres
    date = 2000-06-03
Entry #2: prefix: book
    title = Le Grand-Duché de Luxembourg et la construction européenne
    last = Fally
    first = V.
    publisher = 
    year = 1992
    isbn = 
    location = Luxembourg City
    pages = 
Entry #3: prefix: book
    title = Le Luxembourg face à la construction européenne
    last = Fally
    first = V.
    publisher = 
    year = 1996
    isbn = 
    location = Luxembourg City
    pages = 
Entry #4: prefix: book
    title = Small States in Europe: Challenges and Opportunities
    last = Frentz
    first = Jean-Marie
    publisher = Ashgate
    year = 2010
    isbn = 978-0-7546-7782-6
    location = 
    pages = 
    editor-last = Steinmetz
    editor-first = Robert
    editor-last2 = Wivel
    editor-first2 = Anders
    chapter = The Foreign Policy of Luxembourg
Entry #5: prefix: journal
    title = Luxembourg's Foreign Policy: Does Small Size Help or Hinder?
    last = Hey
    first = Jeanne A. K.
    date = 2002
    journal = Innovation: The European Journal of Social Science Research
    doi = 10.1080/1351161022000027621
    pmid = 
    issue = 3
    volume = 15
    pages = 211–225
Entry #6: prefix: book
    title = Small States in World Politics: Explaining Foreign Policy Behavior
    last = 
    first = 
    publisher = Lynne Rienner Publishers
    year = 2003
    isbn = 978-1-55587-920-4
    location = 
    pages = 
    editor-last = Hey
    editor-first = Jeanne A. K.
Entry #7: prefix: journal
    url = http://onsstad.vdl.lu/uploads/media/ons_stad_71-2002_2-4.pdf
    title = Les relations germano-luxembourgeoises durant les années 30
    last = Hoffmann
    first = Serge
    date = 2002
    journal = Ons Stad
    access-date = 21 January 2016
    issue = 71
    language = French
    trans-title = Germano-Luxembourgish relations in the 1930s
    archive-url = https://web.archive.org/web/20160913104553/http://onsstad.vdl.lu/uploads/media/ons_stad_71-2002_2-4.pdf
    archive-date = 13 September 2016
    url-status = dead
Entry #8: prefix: journal
    url = http://www.forum.lu/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/7631_329_Huberty.pdf
    title = Ein kleiner Fisch im großen Teich Luxemburger Verhandlungsstragien im Kontext der EU-Institutionen
    last = Huberty
    first = Martine
    date = May 2013
    journal = Forum
    doi = 
    pmid = 
    access-date = 
    issue = 329
    language = German
    pages = 21–23
    trans-title = A small fish in a big pond: Luxembourgish negotiation strategies in the context of EU institutions
Entry #9: prefix: journal
    url = http://www.forum.lu/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/5497_257_Kayser.pdf
    title = La neutralité du Luxembourg de 1918 à 1945
    last = Kayser
    first = Steve
    date = June 2006
    journal = Forum
    doi = 
    pmid = 
    access-date = 21 January 2016
    issue = 257
    pages = 36–39
    language = French
    trans-title = Luxembourg's neutrality from 1918 to 1945
Entry #10: prefix: journal
    title = La politique étrangère du Luxembourg
    last = Wurth
    first = Hubert
    date = 2006
    journal = Revue Internationale et Stratégique
    volume = 61
    doi = 10.3917/ris.061.0217
    pmid = 
    issue = 61
    pages = 217–226
    series = 
    language = French
    trans-title = Luxembourg’s Foreign Policy
```