# Extract by regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I wrote a program in Java using RE to extract several information.

The code aims to extract some information from text file (which after = and before the | sign) that information is located in the middle of {{cite book .....}}

My Code :

```
  final String regex = "(?:\\{\\{cite book\\b[^|]*|\\G(?!^))(?=[^}]*}})\\|([^=]+)=([^|}]+)";

    final Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(regex);
    final Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(wikifile);
    System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    System.out.println("\n BOOK: \n ");



    while (matcher1.find()) {
        if (matcher1.group(1).trim().equals("title")) System.out.println("\n----------------------\n");

        if (matcher1.group(1).trim().equals("title")||matcher1.group(1).trim().equals("first")||matcher1.group(1).trim().equals("last")||matcher1.group(1).trim().equals("auther")||matcher1.group(1).trim().equals("url") || matcher1.group(1).trim().equals("publisher") ||matcher1.group(1).trim().equals("isbn")) {

      System.out.println(matcher1.group(1) + " = " + matcher1.group(2));

    }
    }
```

It works well when the information is in several lines except that when it is in one long line it does not extract all the information that I want and I do not know what the reason is ..

Like

```
{{Cite book|url=https://books.google.es/books?id=HuSQGrRY7F4C|title=Ajax Black Book, New Edition (With Cd)|last=Kogent Solutions Inc|first =|publisher = Dreamtech Press|year=2008|isbn=978-8177228380|location=|pages =40}}
```

I want to extract ( URL , Title ,last,first,publisher,isbn )

but the output is

```
 BOOK: 

url = https://books.google.es/books?id=husqgrry7f4c

----------------------

title = ajax black book, new edition (with cd)
last = kogent solutions inc
```

When the input Like

```
 {{Cite book
|url=https://books.google.es/books?id=HuSQGrRY7F4C
|title=Ajax Black Book, New Edition (With Cd)
|last=Kogent Solutions Inc
|first =
|publisher = Dreamtech Press
|year=2008
|isbn=978-817722838
|location=
|pages =40}} &lt;/ref&gt;
```

the Output look Like

```
 BOOK: 

url = https://books.google.es/books?id=husqgrry7f4c


----------------------

title = ajax black book, new edition (with cd)

last = kogent solutions inc

first  = 

publisher  =  dreamtech press

isbn = 978-817722838

last  =  flanagan

first  =  david
```

**update :** 
I think there is a problem with the pattern (regex), when there is a **Null** or no space between `=` and `|` , when element is **NULL** like `first=|` or `location=|` & it was in one line I don’t know

2- **is there a way to extract (url , title , publisger ..etc) by using `RE` Patron instead of using
`.group(1).trim().equals("title")`**

thank you

Comment: When regex is your hammer everything looks like a thumb.

Answer (score 0):

**Last update**

Regexp to search data with prefix `{{Cite book` only, and select multiple `key=value` pairs separated by pipe `'|'` character:

[(?i:(?<=^|\|)({{Cite\s*book\s*)|(\s*[^{|}\=]+)\s*\=\s*([^{|}]*[ ]*))](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydb9wwnr)

The following code demonstrates this regexp:

```
static final int PREFIX_GROUP = 1;
static final int FIELD_NAME_GROUP = 2;
static final int FIELD_VALUE_GROUP = 3;

// .....
String regex = "(?i:(?<=^|\\|)(\\{\\{Cite\\s*book\\s*)|([^{|}\=]+)\\s*\\=\\s*([^{|}]*[ ]*))";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

String txt = "{{cite book\n | url=https://books.google.es/books?id=HuSQGrRY7F4C\n | \"title\"=Ajax Black Book, New Edition (With Cd)\n | 'last'=Kogent Solutions Inc | fir$$t =| publisher = Dreamtech Press\n|editor_1= \"William Gates III, Jr.\" |some.dashed-field=TestDot.NET|year=2008\n|  isbn=978-8177228380\n|location=\n|key_w/o_value|pages =40|}}";

Matcher match = pattern.matcher(txt);
while (match.find()) {
    if (match.group(PREFIX_GROUP) != null) {
        System.out.println("prefix: " + match.group(PREFIX_GROUP).trim());
    }
    if (match.group(FIELD_NAME_GROUP) != null) {
        String key   = match.group(FIELD_NAME_GROUP).trim();
        String value = match.group(FIELD_VALUE_GROUP).trim();
        System.out.println(key + " = " + value);
    }
}
```

and produces output:

```
prefix: {{cite book
url = https://books.google.es/books?id=HuSQGrRY7F4C
"title" = Ajax Black Book, New Edition (With Cd)
'last' = Kogent Solutions Inc
fir$$t = 
publisher = Dreamtech Press
editor_1 = "William Gates III, Jr."
some.dashed-field = TestDot.NET
year = 2008
isbn = 978-8177228380
location = 
pages = 40
```

Comment: thank you , but i want { cite book  to be exist , becuse there is multiy cites in file . also when i excute it , it give me nothing , i want it to work withe one line and multy ,with spase after or befor | andwithe out

Comment: I updated the regexp to handle the prefix and whitespaces, so you can check it out.

Comment: not work ,, also i think you change my text ( it just an example i use file in my prog) by add some (/n) ,, the problem not in if , i thinl it is in pattren , when i print it with out if it not give me every information after = , it just stop looking after (first=|) ,, becuse no space or line between = & |

Comment: O.K , i got you idea and i think it will be work , but i have {{ citt book , { cite web , and more , i want  (regex = "(?i:(?<=^|\\|)(\\s*\\w+)\\s*\\=\\s*([^{|}]*[ ]*)|(\\{\\{Cite)([\\w\\s]+))";) to be spacefic for ({ cite book) , thank you

Comment: Yes, this idea works according to the output that you specified.  I don't understand what you mean by _to be spacefic for ({ cite book)_   In your previous request you would like it to be working for various prefixes like `cite book` and `cite web`.  And this regexp finds main prefix `cite`and then it defines subprefix in the group(4), which may be book,web, whatever.  Are you able at all to tweak the _free_ solution by yourself to adapt it to your needs and requirements?

Comment: yes , but i do not want one pattern for all cite and use (if with equal ) to extract {cite book , i want pattren to extract  {cit book only ....This is my first time to write a program using RE.

Comment: Updated the pattern and code snippet to select specific prefix `{{Cite book` and then multiple key-value pairs.  If you need to find other specific prefixes such as `{{Cite web` or `{{Cite journal` - just replace the `book` to `web` or `journal` respectively.